# Why does Spotlight display an app icon with a strike through warning?

Tags: spotlight, macos, vlc

When I search Spotlight for an app (see screenshot) it displays the app icon with a white strike through or unavailable icon. In this case the app in question is VLC. When I initially installed VLC, El Capitan could verify the identity of the developer but I was able to run the app anyway. Finder displayed the app icon correctly but fearing some corruption in the download/install process, I uninstalled the app using Terminal and downloaded it again and this time OS X verified the developer identity and all was good. So I'm assuming it has something to do with the issue from the initial install and Spotlight has cached an error with the first install.

Could this be the issue? I do not have any issues with VLC, nor did I before, but it's just one of those things that annoys me as I'm an avid Spotlight user.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm via a search that you don't have multiple copies (maybe in the trash)

Comment: @SamanthaCatania no I do not have multiple copies however, the issue has now been resolved though I'm not sure how. All I had done since replicating the issue to take a screenshot, I enabled FileVault and restarted my Mac.

Comment: Glad the issue is solved, seems like it's a little bug from apple then